# php function not cycling through all users, just first user

Tags: php, sql

the following php function is only working for one user record, not all user records with a value of "1" in the weekly_email_f1 column, any ideas?

```
function getSummaryEmailInfo() {
    $sql = "
      SELECT u.id, u.master_id, u.email
      FROM user AS u
      WHERE u.weekly_email_fl = 1
    ";
    $query = $this->db->query( $sql );
    $users = $query->result_array();

    foreach ( $users as &$user ) {
      $user_id = ( $user['master_id'] == '0' ) ? $user['id'] : $user['master_id'];

      $sql = "
        SELECT ui.custom_name
        FROM user_item AS ui
        WHERE ui.user_id = '" . $user_id . "'
        AND added_to_list_dt IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY added_to_list_dt DESC
        ;
      ";
      $query = $this->db->query( $sql );
      $user['s_list'] = $query->result_array();
    }
    return $users;
  }
```

There are multiple users with weekly_email_f1 = 1. i think there is something wrong with how the result_array(); is being populated but cannot figure it out, yet...

```
function getUserInfo( $user_id ) {
    $query = $this->db->query( "
      SELECT name AS first_name, email, zip_code, weekly_email_fl
      FROM user
      WHERE id = '" . $user_id . "'
    ;" );
    if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
      $results = $query->result_array();
      $results = $results[0];
    } else {
      $results = null;
    }
    return $results;
  }
```

Comment: have you tested the function without the foreach-loop to check whether the problem is inside or outside of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
while($users = $query->result_array()) {
    /* You can use $users['master_id'] here */
}
```

Comment: thanks Burak.  so, all current "foreach" code should live between the brackets? { }

Comment: Sorry, you must remove the foreach, in while $users['master_id'] will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is only 1 user with weekly_email_f1 = 1
2. $query->result_array(); returns only first/last/one row.

Comment: thanks, added some more detail about... multiple users have weekly_email_f1=1.